# how to set a computer wide password not just for Windows or Linux?

Tags: passwords

I want to set a password that you'll have to type down before even seeing the option to choice the os to run. Or, in the unlikely situation that there is nothing as such, what is the earliest time you can set a password.

I have an ASUS mother board, I can't tell you what model right now though, I will in a bit though(six hours!)

Comment: `what is the earliest time you can set a password.` .. Most BIOS' have a password protect option that don't allow the computer to boot (or POST on some), but that only protects 'first run' type of attacks (i.e. what can I do at first on this computer). If I can access the HDD, then a BIOS password won't matter much. You could also do full disk encryption and have a special boot loader that only allows booting to the OS menu if you enter the correct password (on top of a BIOS password too if you wanted) ... there are options, it just depends on exactly what you'd like to see?

Comment: Be aware that BIOS passwords are very easy to reset.

Comment: @BenN depends on the type of pc, some bios passwords are stored on a separate chip and cannot be cracked in the usual way.

Answer (score 1):

For a Desktop or Laptop, you mean a BIOS password (maybe called or found in the EFI on newer computers)?

Go into the computer's setup right at boot, by pressing a key, often F10 or DEL or F1, maybe ESC, F12, F8... should be a message at boot time saying what to push. On an ASUS it *should* be the DEL key.

Then go to the Security. In ASUS it *should* be in "Advanced Mode (F7)" -> Security

Here's a slow video walking through the [ASUS Z87 UEFI BIOS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hr3WT46qsS8) from 2011.

---

Of course, there are fairly easy ways to clear a BIOS password, especially if someone physically has the computer.

If you're worried about someone stealing your computer and not being able to use it, then you should really **lock it in a safe that's bolted to something immovable.**

Encrypting your data would be a good idea too, just keep backup copies (of the data AND the encryption keys/header) somewhere safe & secure.

I don't know of any other answers that would stop someone from removing and erasing anything on a hard drive, or swapping for their own hard drive and enjoying your old hardware themselves. There are security programs that can try to track & find & stop thieves, but I don't think they could survive clearing the BIOS and erasing the whole drive.

Comment: Ah, cheers, that's what, I think, I want. I can't watch the video at the moment as I am on 3G but I will watch in a bit though(in six hours.)

Comment: The video's really not that great, just an overview of the BIOS screens. Only options you'd want is advanced mode -> security

Comment: I've seen some places have their desktop computer towers/boxes (with the CPU & motherboard & HD, all that stuff) locked inside of desks with excellent ventilation, almost like a cage, with just the wires leading out... that might be a workable solution to keep a computer tower secure from thieves and people who might open it up and take/reset stuff, and still be able to use it yourself. Clearing a BIOS password on a tower takes a minute, if someone can remove the battery or set the "clear BIOS" jumper, and laptops have tricks to clear their BIOS's too. Physical security would trump software